# Рефакторинг поиска в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, поиск, рефакторинг

Как правильно будет переписать эту вот часть кода?

```
roles = [{'Id': 1, 'Name': 'Модератор'}, {'Id': 2, 'Name': 'Пользователь'}]
participant_ = {'Name': 'Elmir', 'Surname': 'I-de', 'RoleId': 1}
...
current_role = None
for role in roles:
  if role['Id'] == participant_['RoleId']:
    current_role = UserRole(
      id=role['Id'],
      name=role['Name']
    )
    break
...
# использование current_role
```

Почему-то мне кажется что есть способ сделать это лучше (оптимизированнее) чем сейчас.

Comment: Можно роли хранить в словаре, где ключ - id роли. Тогда можно будет получать роль через `roles[participant_['RoleId']]`

Comment: @insolor Хммм, идея прикольная, ща попробую

Answer (score 1):

Впрочем я сделал как посоветовал в комментариях **insolor** (Благодарен за идею).
И получилось вот так:

```
roles = {}
async for role in await fetch_roles():
  roles[role['Id']] = role['Name']
...
try:
  p_role_id = participant_['RoleId']
  current_role = UserRole(
    id=p_role_id,
    name=roles[p_role_id]
  )
except KeyError:
  current_role = None
```